# Use mongoosastic "search" query with mongo query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I'm using elasticsearch together with [Mongoosastic](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic) plugin. I'm querying users, and I would like to retrieve only users that belong to certain group that has a specific object ID. How can I add object ID to search? Basic search (no ID) look like this:

```
User.search({
  query_string: {
    query: req.body.query + '*' // '*' used for wildcard matching
  }

}, {hydrate: true}, (err, results) => {
...
```

And here is my Schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    es_indexed:true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    es_indexed:true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    es_indexed:true
  },
  password: {type: String},
  _team: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team'}, //Object Id I'm trying to filter
});
```

I've tried passing

```
User.find()
```

before searching, and adding _team to query string

```
query_string: {
    query: req.body.query + '*',
    _team: req.team
  }
```

Both approaches predictably didn't work. What is a correct way to do it?